# How to connect PostgreSQL RDS to spring boot in elastic beanstalk?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a spring boot app that can already connect to a local Postgres in my laptop. I uploaded my spring boot jar file to elastic beanstalk and it is deployed fine I can see everything in my app except it cannot connect to the Postgres db that I created in RDS.

I have tried putting the db identifier of the rds db instance name and the master password in the application properties file, but does not work.

```
#cloud.aws.rds.mydbinstanceidentifier
#cloud.aws.rds.testdbspringiloilo.password=mydbmasterpassword
```

When I try to request for an object coming from the DB it shows a whitelabel page telling me it timed out.

[image]

Comment: Can you show your pom.xml I assume there are missing dependencies

Comment: Hi Simon here is the link to the pom file https://www.dropbox.com/s/dbclfjg3stvh068/pom.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Your application cannot reach the RDS instance and is timing out. Make sure that:

1- The security group has an ingress rule allowing connections form the subnet/security group of your application on the database port (5432 by default for Postgres)
2- The Access list for the subnet where your RDS instance is launched is allowing traffic incoming from your Beanstalk environment.
3- You configured the right endpoint and port in your properties file.

Also Consider using environment variables for your secrets instead of storing them as plain text in your application files.

Comment: Thanks Walid, I will perform the check.

Comment: Upon creation of the spring app in elastic beanstalk, I have added the snapshot of the rds in the configuration page before deploying. Which I think that will make sure the VPC/Sec group both in the app and RDS will allow traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You try to us cloud.aws.rds configuration but do not use Spring Cloud AWS.

You need additional dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Please read more about Spring Cloud AWS in the official documentation:
https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-aws

There is also a good sample: https://github.com/codeurjc/spring-cloud-aws-sample

Comment: Link to project is broken

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here's what I did that solve the problem. I don't know which among these solved it actually.

1. I added a new rule to open port 5432 in vpc. (This made me confuse because shouldn't the configuration page made that when executing the script since I explicitly added a Postgres rds snapshot?)
2. I added a new dependency to the pom file, which I'm not quite sure if this really matters since I can already run the app but just can't connect to the DB.

   org.springframework.boot
   spring-boot-starter-web
3. Instead of using the db identifier I used the endpoint address of the snapshot.

Thanks for all the input guys! cheers!